# How to install package and its dependencies into specified folder with poetry?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-poetry, aws-lambda-layers

I have a `poetry` managed package and I would like to install/copy this package together with its dependencies into a specified folder so I can `zip` it and use that archive for an AWS Lambda layer.

One option is resorting to `pip` and use `pip install ... -t ...`. That seems to work b/c `pip` references the virtual environment managed by `poetry`. But this approach doesn't seem optimal to me. Is it possible to achieve this with `poetry` itself?

Comment: Looks like a [`poetry bundle`](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/pull/2682) command is in the works but it isn't merged in yet. [`shiv`](https://github.com/linkedin/shiv) is another tool I've seen suggested that could do the job.

Comment: I guess, I'll stick with `pip` for now and wait for the `bundle` command.